# SwiftUI: Presenting sheet from VStack item doesn't work on iOS 14

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to present a sheet from an item in a VStack. The following code works on iOS 13.7 but not on iOS 14:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListRow: View {
    @State var showingSheet: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingSheet = true
        }) {
            Text("Tap me")
        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showingSheet, content: {
            NavigationView {
                Text("Hello")
            }
        })
    }
}

struct ListRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListRow()
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingModal: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                ForEach (0..<10) {_ in
                    ListRow().padding()
                }
            }.navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                self.showingModal = true
            }, label: {
                Text("TAP")
            })).sheet(isPresented: self.$showingModal, content: {
                Text("Testing main modal")
            })
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

However, when I replace the VStack with a List, it seems to work.

Is this intended behaviour or a bug in SwiftUI on iOS 14? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Tobias Timpe

Comment: Similarly, I had `.sheet` modifier added to one of the root view under `Group { ... }` tag. After that, all `.sheet` modifier added to children views did not work. It took forever to find out, but it looks like you can only have 1 `.sheet` modifier in the tree. So I added the modifier to individual tag, such as `Button` or `Text` instead of  `VStack` or `Group`.

Answer (score 5):

I think it the issue is presenting `.sheet()` twice on the same view.

As `VStack` is non-dynamic, I expect that the `.sheet` of the `ListRow` and the `VStack` are applied to the same construct under the hood, just like you'd call it twice on the upper level:

```
TextView("Foo")
.sheet(isPresented: $showA) { Text("A") }
.sheet(isPresented: $showB) { Text("B") } // Does not work, only one sheet is allowed
```

So either you show only one sheet and have logic in the sheet whether to show "Hello" or "Testing main modal" or you use a List:)

Comment: Good point. Much changed under the hood I guess, I have found many things that changed behaviour. I guess it was undefined before and still is undefined ‍♂️.

Comment: How would I implement this then? I need to pass the model of the LIstRowItem to the sheet and present another sheet from that sheet.

Comment: I use shared observableObject models with a published enum that handles all different sheet types shown. And use [`.sheet(item:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:))

Comment: Would you consider this behaviour to be a bug?

Comment: Hard to tell in SwiftUI what is a bug and not with this sparse documentation 